# No overload for 'ParentSelect_RowCommand' matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventHandler'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am getting this error:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0123: No overload for
>   'ParentSelect_RowCommand' matches delegate
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventHandler'

Source Error:

Line 14:         Submit a Movie click Submit Movie
Line 15:         
Line 16:     
Line 17:         
Line 18:

Here's my code behind:

```
  namespace Sample
         {
public partial class ContentPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }

    protected void ParentSelect_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewRowEventHandler e)
    {

    }

    protected void ParentSelect_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change argument type to `GridViewCommandEventArgs`

```
protected void ParentSelect_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

}
```

You can inspect delegate signature in VisualStudio in ObjectInspector or just find it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventhandler%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)